# Swift Auth0 access code results in unauthorized access but nothing in Auth0 logs

Tags: node.js, swift, nestjs, auth0, react-admin

I have a nestJS backend protected with Auth0.  I am able to successfully access the backend from react-admin by including the access token in the authorization header (`Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`)

However, I seem to have an issue when trying to access the same backend from a Swift iOS app.  I have followed the Auth0 tutorials and am able to confirm successful user login and access to user profile.  However, when I try to make a request to the nestJS backend, I receive a 401 Unauthorized error. Interestingly, nothing is recorded in the Auth0 logs.

Link to Auth0 tutorial: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ios-swift/04-calling-apis

```
let path = "\(baseURL)\(endpoint.rawValue)"
        
guard let url = URL(string: path)
else { preconditionFailure("Bad URL") }
        
var headers: [String:String] = [:]
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        
// if access token is set then set Authorization headers
if (accessToken != nil) {
    headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(accessToken!)"
    print("Bearer \(accessToken!)")
}
        
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "\(method)"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
// check if body exists
if (body != nil) {
    request.httpBody = body!
}

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil
    else { completion(.failure(.serverError)); return }
            
    do {
        guard let data = data
        else { completion(.failure(.serverError)); return }
                
        guard let object : [[String: AnyObject]] = try JSONSerialization.object(with: data) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
        else {
            print("Unable to convert from data")
            return
        }
        
        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: .prettyPrinted)
        else {
            print("Unable to prettify")
            return
        }

        guard let jsonString = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            print("Unable to convert to string")
            return
        }
                
         print("JSON: \(jsonString)")
                
         completion(Result.success(object))
     } catch {
         completion(Result.failure(.parsingError))
     }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

`baseURL` is a string that points to my nestJS backend.
`endpoint` is an enum of endpoints, for example `\user`

Using Proxyman I am able to confirm that the endpoint is hit with the correct headers. Screenshot below.

[image: Proxyman screenshot of headers]

Additionally, using postman I am able to successfully login and also make a get request to protected data. Screenshot below.

[image]

Any ideas to what might be the cause? Let me know if I should add any additional details.

**UPDATE**
I decoded the successful (react-admin) and unsuccessful (iOS) JWT tokens and noticed the following differences:

`aud` in the successful JWT contains an array of audiences that include the API registerd on Auth0 as well as an auth0 endpoint `https://xxxxx.us.auth0.com/userinfo`

`azp` is only present in the successful JWT and contains my clientID

`aud` in the unsuccessful token contains the clientID

`scope` and `permissions` is missing from unsuccessful token.

Ps. also posted on Auth0 Community
https://community.auth0.com/t/access-token-when-obtained-from-ios-results-in-401-unauthorized-while-from-react-admin-is-ok/71115

Comment: take a step forward, are you using a debugger tool to trace the network requests? can you please check the requests from the client? is the token attached successfully and is in the "Authorization" property?

Comment: @novonimo with Proxyman I was able to confirm that the correct headers are set and sent to the endpoint.

Comment: can you also do a successful login from "postman"? is your backend side work correctly with postman API calls?

Comment: @novonimo confirmed successful login and retrieving user data using the access token from Auth0 (updated post). Additional observation: Now if I swap the access token with the one I obtained through the iOS device I get the same error... Unauthorized

Comment: is the "baseURL" which you used in your swift client use the "https" or "http"?

Comment: https. I've also confirmed by printing `path`

Comment: try to remove "headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json" " from swift client (try to send headers as same as postman)

Comment: @novonimo thanks for the suggestion. I commented out the `//        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"` but still the same issue.  I also checked CORS but that isn't the problem.  Confused to why the access token (or JWT) i get from Auth0 from the iOS app doesn't work....I must be missing something...

Comment: do you have access to the backend service? can you print out the "request"? as I'm not a swift developer, I can't confirm that your client works fine as your expectation

Comment: Use https://jwt.io/ to decode and compare the working and non-working JWT. Due to a configuration issue, the iOS app might get a JWT that is valid for a different service.

Comment: BTW: It's normal that you don't see any log entry in Auth0 related to the 401 error. Three systems are involved: iOS app, Auth0 and nestJS backend. In the communication between iOS and Auth0, a token is issued. This part is successful. The problem is in the interaction between iOS and nestJS backend. And in order to validate the token, nestJS doesn't need to contact Auth0 as you are using bearer tokens. The token is signed and that's sufficient for nestJS to validate it. So: no interaction with Auth0, no log entry.

Comment: @Codo thanks! I spotted some differences, such as missing permissions and also the audience being an array in the successful JWT, while the iOS one is just the clientID.  I feel a lot closer to figuring out what went wrong! Also appreciate your explanation about why I don't see anything in the logs on Auth0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `audience` was set when requesting access tokens from the react-admin, while I did not include this in the swift login implementation.

Decoding the JWT on jwt.io and the following thread lead to this conclusion.
https://community.auth0.com/t/access-token-too-short-jwt-malformed/9169/11?u=kennethphough

Adding the audience in the following code resulted in the correct jwt being returned and successful access to backend.

```
Auth0
    .authentication()
    .login(
        usernameOrEmail: self.email,
        password: self.password,
        realm: "Username-Password-Authentication",
        audience: "<YOUR_AUDIENCE>",     // <- This is what I forgot
        scope: "openid profile email"
)
```